# How can I transform the intrinsic and extrinsic matrix into opengl projection and view matrix correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have some 3D points near origin, camera intrinsic and extrinsic matrix. I can get correct 2D points through projectPoints(using x = intrinsic * extrinsic * X) function in opencv. But when I want to render these 3D points using opengl, it can't work well. 
I just transformed intrinsic matrix into glm mat4 as follow:

```
proj[0][0] = 2 * fx / width;
proj[1][0] = 0.0f;
proj[2][0] = (2 * cx - width) / width;
proj[3][0] = 0.0f;
proj[0][1] = 0.0f;
proj[1][1] = -2 * fy / height;
proj[2][1] = (height - 2 * cy) / height;
proj[3][1] = 0.0f;
proj[0][2] = 0.0f;
proj[1][2] = 0.0f;
proj[2][2] = -(far_clip + near_clip) / (near_clip - far_clip);
proj[3][2] = 2 * near_clip * far_clip / (near_clip - far_clip);
proj[0][3] = 0.0f;
proj[1][3] = 0.0f;
proj[2][3] = 1.0f;
proj[3][3] = 0.0f;
```

The fx,fy are focal length, width and height are the width and height of image, cx and cy is width / 2 and height / 2 (I get camera matrix through it).

Then I transposed the 4*4 extrinsic matrix as glm view matrix because of the column major in opengl. In my shader, I got gl_Position through

```
gl_Position = proj * view * vec4(3Dpointposition, 1.0f)
```

But I got wrong rendering result in screen. I got my camera matrix with the origin in the top-left, and the origin in opengl is in the bottom-left, It also seems that the camera in opencv looks down the positive z-axis but the opengl camera looks down the negetive z-axis. How can I modify the code to the correct version?